# How can I use RABL and extends/partials to generate a consistent JSON object across models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rabl

Our business requirement is that all JSON responses look something like this:

```
{ "status": "ok"
"page": "1",
"perPage: "20",
"totalPages": "3",
"totalRecords": "54",
"records": [ { "id": 1234, "name": "Lorem ipsum } ] }
```

In other words, the meat of the response is the set of "records", but it needs to be wrapped with the status, paging attributes, etc. I'd like to use RABL to generate this. Is there a way to use extends or a partial to build this structure across all my objects in a DRY way?

I'd love to do something like this:

**app/views/widgets/index.rabl**

```
collection @widgets, :object_root => false
attributes :id, :name
extends "layouts/base" , :locals => { results: @widgets }
```

**app/views/layouts/base.rabl**

```
node( :status ) { 'ok' }
node( :pages ) { @results.total_pages }
```

**app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @widgets = Widget.paginate( page: params[:page] )
end
```

This does not work as-is.

To clarify, I want to set a local as @results which I can then use inside the wrapper.

Then, if I want to JSON-ify another object I could do something like:

**app/views/fruits/index.rabl**

```
collection @fruits, :object_root => false
attributes :id, :flavor
extends "layouts/base" , :locals => { results: @fruits }
```

**app/controllers/fruits_controller.rb**

```
def index
  @fruits = Fruit.paginate( page: params[:page] )
end
```

And, not need to modify layouts/base, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a JSON layout, like you would use one for HTML. I'm not sure how you would `yield` using RABL, but you could probably do something similar. When we receive a JSON request, we respond with some metadata and a block of HTML to be put into the page, so we have:

`layouts/application.json.haml`:

```
!= {  js_to_eval: @tracking.flush_mp_js + @tracking.flush_ga_js, 
      flash: flash_to_raw_json,
      html: yield }.to_json
```

The `yield` renders the HAML template corresponding to the route, just as it would in a normal `layouts/application.html.haml`. I'm sure you can do something similar.

Comment: I'd love to use a "pure" RABL solution, but this is nice as I can refactor it later. Thank you. I'm going to hold off accepting this as the answer for a little bit.

Comment: Ahah - I came across this answer and thought "my that code looks awful familiar". Must have a great author ;)